# Test for LocalDateTime UTC method

Tags: java, datetime, junit

I have a method `toUTC()`

```
public ZonedDateTime toUTC(LocalDateTime ldt) {
   return ldt.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).withZoneSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);
}
```

I would like to write a test for this method but I'm not really sure the best way to go about it? Can someone point me in the right direction? I'm not much of a date time and time zone expert

Comment: Have you thought about anything? Tried anything? Searched information from anywhere? Could you put some words on what’s stopping you?

Comment: the time zones, daylight savings time specifically. I want it system time zone safe and daylight savings time safe. I'm not really sure about daylight savings time, utc and how it relates to system local time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your method cannot be compiled. I get

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from ZonedDateTime to LocalDateTime

In principle, that’s fine because it allows us at least a degree of TDD: writing the test before (finishing) the method. On the other hand, writing a test is a challenge when we’re not sure about the requirements for the method. Should it return a `LocalDateTime` as the current signature suggests, or rather a `ZonedDateTime` as the return statement tries to, or perhaps an `OffsetDateTime` since we know the target offset, or even an `Instant`, since these are always in UTC?

I will however narrow this answer down to testing a method that has already been written since I think this is what you were asking about. I am assuming a return type of `OffsetDateTime` and a method like this:

```
public static OffsetDateTime toUTC(LocalDateTime ldt) {
    return ldt.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
            .toOffsetDateTime()
            .withOffsetSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);
}
```

The next challenge is that our method depends on `ZoneId.systemDefault()`. This dependency reduces testability since we want the test to run in all time zones, but the method shouldn’t produce the same result in all time zones. I have not searched for ways to manipulate the system default time-zone, they may exist, and there are mocking frameworks that will allow us to stub `ZoneId.systemDefault()` and control the result it returns to our method. The simple way I will use here is a refactoring that takes the troublesome dependency out:

```
public static OffsetDateTime toUTC(LocalDateTime ldt) {
    return fromZoneToUtc(ldt, ZoneId.systemDefault());
}

static OffsetDateTime fromZoneToUtc(LocalDateTime ldt, ZoneId timeZone) {
    return ldt.atZone(timeZone).toOffsetDateTime().withOffsetSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);
}
```

I am giving up on testing the first, very simple method above, but testing the second, where all the logic happens, can now be done simply with constant data, for example

```
    assertEquals(OffsetDateTime.of(2017, 4, 12, 14, 0, 0, 0, ZoneOffset.UTC),
            fromZoneToUtc(LocalDateTime.of(2017, 4, 12, 16, 0), ZoneId.of("Europe/Berlin")));
```

I will leave it to you to find some good test cases. I am sure you can think of some in different time zones, some zones that have DST and some that haven’t. Zones east and west of UTC and a zone that coincides with UTC (at the time of year tested). And some times in summer and some in winter, and preferrably some that are close to the DST crossovers (spring and fall).

Comment: Hmm, I didn't try it in java. I actually wrote it in Kotlin originally. It was working there, however I didn't try the java version out. You know the problem there is that the return type is an optional declaration in Kotlin) . It should be a ZonedDateTime result

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I'm away from the computer now but will digest it tomorrow